# CSS: How to eliminate border for a particular row/column in the table

Tags: html, css

I have the follwoing table:

[image]

I'm looking for the way to remove border from "Row1 - Column1" cell, so it looks like the following:

[image]

This is my html:

```
<table id="tblContent" style="width:1000px;">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Row 1 - Column1</td>
     <td colspan="4">Row1 - Column1=2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
```

THis is my css:

```
#tblContent
{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#tblContent td
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:small;
}
```

How can I do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```css
#tblContent tr:first-child > td:first-child {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
#tblContent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#tblContent td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: small;
}
#tblContent tr:first-child > td:first-child {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblContent" style="width:1000px;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Row 1 - Column1</td>
    <td colspan="4">Row1 - Column1=2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element you want to remove the border from is always the first cell in the first row. You can set up a css rule that targets this using the `first-child` selector.

Alternatively, you can also give that cell a class and target the rule to it.

Using `first-child`:

```css
#tblContent
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#tblContent td
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:small;
}

#tblContent tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblContent" style="width:1000px;">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Row 1 - Column1</td>
     <td colspan="4">Row1 - Column1=2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Using a class:

```css
#tblContent
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#tblContent td
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:small;
}

#tblContent .noBorder {
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblContent" style="width:1000px;">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5" class="noBorder" >Row 1 - Column1</td>
     <td colspan="4">Row1 - Column1=2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it, just fint first table row and first table column of this row.

```css
#tblContent
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#tblContent td
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:small;
    height: 20px;
} 
#tblContent tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
  }
```

```html
<table id="tblContent" style="width:1000px;">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5">Row 1 - Column1</td>
     <td colspan="4">Row1 - Column1=2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/acn7k7e6/

**CSS**

```
#tblContent
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#tblContent td
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:small;
} 

#tblContent td:first-child {
    border: medium none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose try table will be built for a loop as for or while so try to assign id for the row and column with id in html or use data-row and data-col in this way you will know what column in what row you want to eliminate or modify whatever you want.